# After grails 3 upgrade, less file are not picked up for compilation

Tags: grails, less, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

I am trying to upgrade one of my projects to grails 3.x.
Most of the things are working as expected, except the less pipeline plugin.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.6.7'
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
    }
}

....
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
....
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.6.7'
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'
}
```

In config I have this line (which suppose to control the compilation):
`grails.assets.less.compiler = 'less4j'`

Also, my asserts folder looks like this:
[image]

When I am running the app, none of the less files getting compiled and/or included on the page.

My main.less file looks like this:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../vendor/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
@import "rrm.less";

rest of a file...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Check if changing `runtime` to `asset` for `less-asset-pipeline` in your dependencies helps. asset's gradle plugin adds this dependency scope. It should be `assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'`. Also remove dependency to `less-asset` from build-script dependencies, as only gradle plugin should be there.

Comment: hmm, after this change I am getting an error: `ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.RuntimeException: File was not sourced from the same ScanDirectory /Users/ShurikAg/Dev/grails/priz/grails-app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less scanDir: /Users/ShurikAg/Dev/grails/priz/grails-app/assets/images`

Comment: Is it even allowed to reference files outside of `stylesheets` folder?

Comment: I don't think this is allowed. can't you move them to stylesheets and check if this solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error look like linked to there is one more ../ on your js with require